# Returning different data types from a function in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing some kind of buffer parser that takes vector of unsigned char bytes as an input,for example

```
Datatype getvalue(vector<unsigned char> buffer) 
{
  // compute value
  If vector contains 2 bytes then unsigned int will be returned
  If vector contains 4 bytes then unsigned long will be returned 
  If 12 bytes then date time will
 be returns 
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Return types need to be known at compile time. You can't really have that depend on run-time information.

Comment: If you can use C++17 standard, std::variant is what you might want: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion,but I have to use c++11

Comment: for c++11 use boost::variant, it's mostly the same and std::variant

Comment: @cigien using  polymorphism can't we achive it at run time. Like all my classes are inherited from a base class and then I can return base class from a function

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this.

A function can only return one type. You could use some sort of type erasure (`std::variant`/`std::any` and others) but as you are bound to C++11, you can resort to the following: Instead of returning the value from the function pass it to a function...

```
struct Consumer {
     void operator()(int x) { ... }
     void operator()(float x) { ... }
     void operator()(time_t t) { ... }
};

void getValue(Consumer& c,vector<unsigned char> buffer) {
      if (...) {
         int data; 
         c(data);
      } else if (...) {
         float data;
         c(data);
      } else if (...) {
         time_t data;
         c(data);
      }
}
```

> I will store these values in a vector and that do some computation on each value and then will concat thses values to generate an output string

A vector can only store `int` or `float`, so we are back at step zero. However, to add them to a string all you need is a stringstream:

```
void getValue(std::stringstream& s,vector<unsigned char> buffer) {
      if (...) {
         int data; 
         s << data;
      } else if (...) {
         float data;
         s << data;
      } else if (...) {
         time_t data;
         s << data;
      }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response but could you please elborate some more {... } how will I get back the value

Comment: @dheeraj what are those values? How do you want to use them?

Comment: I will store these values in a vector and that do some computation on each value and then will concat thses values to generate an output string

Comment: no I will not convert them directly in string ,I will return thses values Nd perform some computation then I only I will convert, your first approach is better, if you can explain it more

Comment: @dheeraj then you can do that computation in `Consumer::operator()` and push it to the stream also there

Comment: if I am wrong please correct me will it be like visitor pattern

Comment: @dheeraj yes, c++17 added quite some support for visitors, but as you can only use c++11...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use some [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) type.

### A C++ function has one return type, not several of them.

In C++17 consider using the [`std::variant` template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Or code your own implementation, using some `union` in your `class`. Then follow the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html) (even in C++11).

### Read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) for more, and the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

See also [this C++ reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/).

If you compile with a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), enable all warnings and debug info, so [use](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and perhaps [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) and the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) or the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

**Look for inspiration into the source code of existing open source projects** on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) (e.g. [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), [Qt](https://qt.io/), [fish](https://fishshell.com/), [Boost](https://www.boost.org/), etc... and those mentioned above)

Perhaps consider passing (as a second or more arguments to your `getvalue`) one or several [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (so practically some [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)) processing the results of different type. Think in terms of [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) and [contination passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) using more a [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to return different data types from a single function. However, you can achieve something similar using polymorphism. If all your return types are derived from a single base class, you can make your function return a pointer to that base class, which in turn may point to any one of the derived classes. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class Datatype
{
public:
    virtual string gettype() = 0;
    virtual void performOp() = 0;
    virtual stringstream& concat(stringstream&) = 0;
    virtual ~Datatype() {};
};

class UnsignedInt : public Datatype
{
    unsigned int val;
    string type { "unsigned int" };
public:
    UnsignedInt(unsigned int v): val(v) {}
    string gettype() {return type;}
    void performOp() { /*perfrom uint specific operations here eg. val = func1(val); */}
    stringstream& concat(stringstream& out) {out<<val; return out;}
    unsigned int getval() {return val;}
    ~UnsignedInt() {}
};

class UnsignedLong : public Datatype
{
    unsigned long val;
    string type { "unsigned long" };
public:
    UnsignedLong(unsigned long v): val(v) {}
    string gettype() {return type;}
    void performOp() { /*perfrom ulong specific operations here eg. val = func2(val); */}
    stringstream& concat(stringstream& out) {out<<val; return out;}
    unsigned long getval() {return val;}
    ~UnsignedLong() {}
};

Datatype* getvalue(vector<unsigned char> buffer)
{
    if(buffer.size() == 2)
    {
        // some logic
        return new UnsignedInt(23);
    }
    else if(buffer.size() == 4)
    {
        //some logic
        return new UnsignedLong(2564);
    }
    else
        return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    vector<unsigned char> vec{'2' , '3'};
    stringstream out;
    Datatype *val = getvalue(vec);
    val->performOp();  // perfroms uint specific operation
    val->concat(out);
    out<<',';
    vector<unsigned char> vec1{'2' , '5' , '6' , '4'};
    val = getvalue(vec1);
    val->performOp();  // perfroms ulong specific operation
    val->concat(out);
    cout<<out.str()<<endl;
    delete val;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the problem with this design is everytime after calling getvalue function I need to put if-else conditions. It will make the code clumsy, can you suggest any solution to avoide above mentioned issue?

Comment: The efficiency of your code will depend on your design. The if-else conditions are not mandatory, you may need it or you may not, depends on your requirement and what you want to do with the return values.  For example, if i had created a virtual member function called 'printVal()' and had it overridden in each of the derived classes, then i would not have required that if-else block in the main function. Simply calling the printVal() funtion would print the type and the value. You may want to design your application in a way that will let you use the base class pointer and some interfaces

Comment: (contd) However, once in a while you may find the need to use if-else/switch statements. if-else/switch blocks are not necessarily bad or clumsy. It is used almost everywhere. Unless you are writing a low latency application such as  packet processing/ forwarding, where even the slightest delay may have implications, using if-else should not be an issue.

Comment: (contd) anyways, To answer your question, " everytime after calling getvalue function I need to put if-else conditions" - not necessarily. If you implement proper interfaces, you can continue using the base class pointer.

Comment: thanks for your valuable comments, I thought like everytime I call getvalue function I need to put if-else statement. Printval is definitely not my usecase. As I have mentioned I am writing a buffer parser, that contains these datatypes, so my buffer parser will return collection of these datatypes, and i will use that collection for further processing, so if you guide me how should I design the interfaces so that I can avoid multiple use of if-else it would be great help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have edited the code to include two additional interfaces. performOp(), concat(). Please check. Btw, i have been ignoring couple of things in your code: 1. using vector as a buffer.  2. 'returning uint if size is 2 bytes' (for most of the modern compilers, size of int is 4 bytes). I am sure you have valid reasons for using them. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Basically it's for an iot device, that still has 2 bytes integer and 4 bytes long. I am working on parsing a buffer that is a collection of such Data types, if you like and have some time then you can also guide me on some good ideas to how to parse such a buffer.

Comment: You will find plenty of help and guidance on this platform. More importantly, you will learn different ways to solve a problem, which i think is invaluable. If you found my answer helpful, please up-vote/accept it.