# Why is throwing exceptions not considered a technique to return different data types at runtime?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, return-type

I've this in mind:

```
// This is called at multiple locations and each handles the returned object
// differently. Handling also differs depending on the returned object type.
void GetObject() {
    // Check runtime condition

    // Object1 and Object2 are completely dissimilar and do not share a base class.
    if (condition1) {
        // Operations to prepare for construction of Object1
        throw Object1{ var1, var2, var3 };
    }
    if (condition2) {
        // Operations to prepare for construction of Object2
        throw Object2{ var4, var5 };
    }
    throw MyException{};
}

// Usage example
int main() {
    try {
        GetObject();
    }
    catch (const Object1& obj1) {
        // Object1-specific handling
    }
    catch (const Object2& obj2) {
        // Object2-specific handling
    }
    catch (const MyException& e) {
        // Error handling
    }
}
```

Curiously, the answers to questions about returning different data types do not mention this technique at all:

- [Returning different data type depending on the data (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930932/returning-different-data-type-depending-on-the-data-c)
- [function which is able to return different types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649136/function-which-is-able-to-return-different-types)
- [Returning different data types from a function in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63603653/returning-different-data-types-from-a-function-in-c)

Is there any particular reason for this? The only reason I can think of is that it's unorthodox, otherwise this seems like the simplest and cleanest approach - no 3rd party libraries, no need to upgrade to C++17, no additional abstractions.

#### Update

As many have pointed out in the comments, `std::variant` would solve the problem nicely, but it requires C++17 or the boost library; unfortunately my project is unable to use either at the moment.

#### Update 2

Thanks everyone for your inputs. They were very helpful in making me think through the various design options and highlight areas where I overlooked. I've selected the answer below as it directly addresses the reason why this technique is not considered for use. The other 2 answers proposed alternative techniques, so do take a look at them if you have similar use cases. For me, I eventually decided on output parameters as the solution due to its simplicity and also my constraints of no C++17 and no boost:

```
bool GetObject(
    std::unique_ptr<Object1>& obj1,
    std::unique_ptr<Object2>& obj2) {
    // Check runtime condition

    if (condition1) {
        // Operations to prepare for construction of Object1
        obj1 = std::make_unique<Object1>(var1, var2, var3);
        return true;
    }
    if (condition2) {
        // Operations to prepare for construction of Object2
        obj2 = std::make_unique<Object2>(var4, var5);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Usage example
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Object1> obj1;
    std::unique_ptr<Object2> obj2;
    if (!GetObject(obj1, obj2)) {
        // Error handling
        return -1;
    }
    if (obj1) {
        // Object1-specific handling
    }
    else {
        // Object2-specific handling
    }
    ...
}
```

Instead of unique_ptr, statically allocating the objects (i.e. on the stack) will also work if the objects aren't too large. But this requires Object1 and Object2 to have member functions that can tell callers whether the class has been initialized.

Comment: This is just normal exception handling code. [Using throw to replace return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713231/using-throw-to-replace-return-in-c-non-void-functions)

Comment: *"Is there any particular reason for this?...."* Seems opinion-based.

Comment: Exceptions have overhead. This will also annoy anybody trying to debug your code (including future you), since the debugger will break on those exceptions (unless you disable that, but then it won't break on actually problematic exceptions either).

Comment: Also, i don't think exceptions should be overused(misused?).

Comment: @user12002570: To clarify, I'm asking because this seems like an obvious solution, but since none of the past answers mention this, I'm wondering whether they're deliberately avoiding this solution due to specific reasons that I'm missing.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: this is a good point, though it can be mitigated depending on tooling. E.g. in visual studio, you can specify the debugger to ignore specific exception object types. So in my example, I can continue to break on MyException but ignore Object1 and Object2.

Comment: Nitpick: `if (condition == true) { ... }` => `if (condition) { ... }`

Comment: The language provides different tools to express different intentions. `std::variant` is a way to return one of distinct types at a time. Exceptions are thrown in exceptional situations, i.e. an error occurred. Misusing exceptions for regular return is possible but confusing for a reader (the concerns about performance impact aside which might be tolerable).

Comment: @wmjdgla why do that trickery when `variant` (or any other tagged-union-like type) can be returned? It's generally agreed that exceptions should be used to indicate errors. Sure, no one can force the programmer to do that, still it seems a wide consensus, why surprise API's user? Moreover, one cannot specify the output types with that kind of interface, or at least it renders the code non-upgradable to newer C++ standards. Tooling and debuggers are yet another thing. Also, environments exist where exceptions are fully disabled due to their overhead (e.g. embedded systems).

Comment: What @Scheff'sCat says. There is a reason function normallu will not return different types based on its input, it is unexpected in the language (and kind of breaks the type system). In many cases either you use std::variant OR you return an (abstract) baseclass. Just do not do this

Comment: Regarding the overhead: it seems [implementations lock a mutex when throwing](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2544r0.html), which is quite bad.

Comment: *Please* don't do this.  You've read the comments, you should pay heed to what people are saying.

Comment: There also the risk that one of the functions that GetObject calls throws an exception, and that exception will be mistaken as GetObject's return value. Plus of course that since it is nonidiomatic, nobody else will understand your code.

Comment: a quick 1 minute search for c++11 variant library got me [mapbox::variant](https://github.com/mapbox/variant) which is header-only.

Comment: I think someone should collect all the good points against exceptions mentioned in comments and write a proper answer (rather then only presenting an alternative and assume it'd be obvious why exceptions are out like I did ;).

Comment: On a previous project, a `throw` would cause the program to fork, one of the forks would continue running, the other fork would core dump so the cause of the exception could be diagnosed. (This took about 10 seconds, real time, for each exception.) Devs would probably get grumpy if core dumps were being created merely for not-exceptional-at-all flow control of alternative return types.  But that was in the 1990s, and times have changed.

Comment: @alagner all great points. Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "one cannot specify the output types...non-upgradable to newer C++ standards"? Specifying the output types is just a matter of throwing different objects and catching them. I also don't see how it would break after upgrading. And just an amusing observation on the point of it being "trickery": if you look at it from another angle, having to use `variant`, a whole-ass library of thousands of lines spanning multiple files, just to achieve something that can be done via a built-in language feature, is much more of a trickery ;)

Comment: @wmjdgla in C++03 one could write sth like this: `void f() throw(foo, bar);` effectively specifying what exception could be thrown (and by default crashing the program if anything else would fly out of the function). This was deprecated and later removed from the standard, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec). But other than that there is no way of telling the caller what the function's output is.

Comment: And yes, I do consider this "trickery" because exceptions as a feature were designed to indicate errors and this is how almost everything uses them exclusively. That being said, imagine your "data-passing exception" needs perform some IO, but that throws for some reason. That's an immediate, unrecoverable crash, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/v5K7eM7zv). Not to mention performance overhead, API predictability etc. Long story short (and zero offence intended): to me such construct would be a total merge-blocker during a code review. And I daresay not only to me.

Comment: Also, any thrown object [must be copyable](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.throw#5). So your function can't "return via throw" a `unique_ptr`, for example. Throwing non-copyable objects is UB, and I have been unfortunate enough to have to debug a problem that was traced back to code that (by mistake) threw a non-copyable object, and boy it was not fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Exceptions are too costly for polymorphism

Exceptions are simply the wrong mechanism for polymorphism.
Throwing an exception is an *extremely* expensive operation:
[image: Graph which compares the relative cost of different benchmarks. All results related to use_error_code are fairly low (50 or lower), but the use_exception bars get dramatically higher (over 4000 for use_exception90) the greater the probability of throwing an exception is.]
*Source: [@Arash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52513707/5740428) containing [this benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/6uk5MBaVaIulNiE5IJncPrl0ShI).*

In this benchmark, the cost of returning an error code is mostly the same no matter how great the probability is.
**Throwing an exception can be over 100x slower.**
It's expensive because

- The stack must be unwound. This is effectively single-threaded and requires synchronization, see [P2544: C++ exceptions are becoming more and more problematic](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2544r0.html).
- Code is run which is probably not cached because exception handling code is never executed normally.
- Exceptions are allocated in dynamic memory.

#### If exceptions are so expensive, when do we use them?

Exceptions are zero-overhead as long as you never throw them, but if you ever do, you're in for a wild ride.
That's why, as the name says, they are used for *exceptional* situations, like:

- running out of memory on an allocation
- getting an unexpected error from a driver or the operating system
- developer mistakes like accessing the wrong index on `std::vector::at`

In a regular program execution, an exception should never be thrown.

### Alternative ways to return one of N types

This topic has already been discussed to death in the threads you've linked, but just to give you a few options:

- `std::variant` (C++17)
- `std::optional` (C++17) and `std::expected` (C++23) in specific cases
- polymorphic classes

  - possibly wrapped in `std::unique_ptr` (C++11)
- `struct` which simply contains both types, and a tag to say which is active

  - possibly less efficient than a proper `union`, but trivial to implement
- avoiding runtime polymorphism entirely with static polymorphism

  - possibly through templates

Your example is a bit too minimal to say which way works best here.

Answer (score 2):

These are two of the idiomatic way C++ works with polymorphism.

```
#include <memory>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

// Option 1, use std::variant
// and "static" (compile time) polymorphism
struct Object1
{
    void DoSomething() 
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from Object1\n";
    };
};

struct Object2
{
    void DoSomething() 
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from Object2\n";
    };
};

std::variant<Object1, Object2> GetObject(bool return_one)
{
    if (return_one)
        return Object1{};
    else
        return Object2{};
}

// Or use dynamic (runtime) polymorphism
struct ObjectItf
{
    virtual ~ObjectItf() = default;
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

struct DynObject1 : public ObjectItf
{
    void DoSomething() override
    {
         std::cout << "Hello from DynObject1\n";
    }
};

struct DynObject2 : public ObjectItf
{
    void DoSomething() override
    {
         std::cout << "Hello from DynObject2\n";
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<ObjectItf> GetDynObject(bool return_one)
{
    if (return_one)
        return std::make_unique<DynObject1>();
    else
        return std::make_unique<DynObject2>();
}


int main()
{
    auto object = GetObject(true);
    std::visit([](auto& object){ object.DoSomething(); }, object);

    auto object_itf = GetDynObject(true);
    object_itf->DoSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand that std::variant requires C++17 or the boost library, however my project is unable to upgrade to C++17 nor use boost at the moment. Sorry I should have been clearer about this in my question. Also my Object1 and Object2 refer to completely different things, so making them inherit from a base class just for the purpose of polymorphic return type feels too forced.

Comment: @wmjdgla then just have custom variation of variant implemented (I don't want to say "copy-paste from Boost", but looking up Boost's implementation is a reasonable starting point, it's open and with a very loose licensing). 
Or have a function templated on return type (if possible). Really, this depends on your exact use case, which none of us here knows. Using exceptions for it seems like violating the principle of least astonishment for the sake of saving some time to implement the right tools for the job.

Comment: @wmjdgla sloppy speaking `std::variant` is just a union with all bells and whistles added so its typesafe and actually usable. If you cannot use `std::variant` the fallback is a union not to reinvent a wheel.

Comment: @wmjdgla If they are referring to completely different things put them in different functions. What do you hope to gain by this?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai That is indeed very sloppy ;) It mostly aims at preventing all the UB scenarios involved in using unions in C++. So still, never use a union in C++ or really be prepared to read the C++ standard on unions and understand in which way they can go wrong. Also not something I'd recommend ;)

Comment: Why can't you upgrade your compiler? If you have unit tests that is less risky than the code you are proposing

Comment: @alagner I did consider porting over `variant`, but I quickly noped out of it after taking a peek at the source code - it's thousands of lines across multiple files. I've seen a few DIY implementations that are single-file but they're still on the order of 100+ lines and involve arcane template constructs. Compared to throwing exceptions, this feels like an overkill.

Comment: @wmjdgla those 100+ lines are usually specifically constructed to produce the most optimal code the compiler could possibly emit, on the other hand compilers are compiling code under the assumption that exceptions will almost never happen, you get a page-fault and you have to spin up a magnetic disk every time an exception happens, don't use exceptions as a return mechanism, a simple struct that has all your return types and an enum of which type is actually contained will be much faster.

Comment: @PepijnKramer So GetObject actually reads some data off a physical device that's beyond my control. The data is serialised versions of either Object1 or Object2. I don't know which is which until I read and parses the data, so there is no way to separate them into different functions. Upgrading to C++17 is definitely on the roadmap, but currently I have to prioritize other deliverables due to constraints on schedule and requirements.

Comment: @wmjdgla then use optionals, they're significantly easier to implement than variant and return a struct of them: one filled, the rest empty. Ugly, workaround etc. but still way cleaner than what you're trying to do. Or replace optionals with dynamic allocation and empty optionals with null pointer if you really want it to be quick to implement.

Comment: What do you need to do with that data, does that data represent something similar (just in different device specific formats)? And do you know up front which physical device you are connected to? If both are say temperature measurment device you still can have a reusable interface with `virtual std::vector<double> getTemperatures` and a specific implementation class per physical device that also does the translation from device specific format to a vector of doubles. That is what software engineering is all about : abstractions

Comment: @PepijnKramer It's a single device storing 1 of 2 different types of data. There is no way to know which one it is until I read and parse it. The type of data will determine what workflow is presented to the user. The workflows are very different, so I'm not sure it'll make much sense to try to convert them to some standardized format.

Comment: @alagner thanks, I'll take a look at optionals and see how I can use them.

Comment: Ok so read it first. Do a fast check to see which kind of data it is and then pass it on to the appropiate workflow. There is nothing in C++ that says you have to use objects for everyhting. It is perfectly okay to solve functional problems in a functional way. I would even say completely separating the workflows as soon as you can is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I do not understand what this actually achieves. I think your example is too simplified to demonstrate a real use case. Once you need the "returned" objects outside of the catch blocks you are back to square one. Because you then again need something that can hold either an `Object1` or an `Object2`.

On the other hand if you are fine with not getting the objects out of the catch block and having them available on such limited scope, then there are much simpler solutions that are less arcance. What comes to my mind first is a functor with overloaded `operator()`:

```
struct Object1 {};
struct Object2 {};

struct handler {
    void operator()(const Object1&) const { }
    void operator()(const Object2&) const { }
};

void GetObject(const handler& h) {
    // Check runtime condition
    // Object1 and Object2 are completely dissimilar and do not share a base class.
    if (2%2)
    {
        h(Object1{});
    }
    if (1<1)
    {
        h(Object2{});
    }
}
```

This can be made more flexible, eg `handler` can have the actual functions to be executed in either case injected at runtime. `handler` could even store the objects to be picked up later. You do not need to abuse exceptions to achieve what your code achieves.

---

You asked for different function being executed in the two overloads and usage of local variables from different call sites. As mentioned above, you can inject the functions to be called at runtime, and if you need you can also capture local variables:

```
template <typename F1,typename F2>
void GetObject(F1&& f1, F2&& f2) {
    // Check runtime condition
    // Object1 and Object2 are completely dissimilar and do not share a base class.
    if (2%2)
    {
        f1(Object1{});
    }
    if (1<1)
    {
        f2(Object2{});
    }
}

int main() {
    int x = 42;
    int y = 102;
    GetObject([&](const Object1&){ std::cout << x;},[&](const Object2&){ std::cout << y;});
}
```

Comment: I did consider this pattern too. However, `GetObject` is called at multiple places and each place handles the returned object differently from others. Sure I can use polymorphism to define a different `operator()` for each case, but the problem is that the handling requires access to variables local to the callers of `GetObject`. Different handlers require different variables. I'm not sure if there is a clean way to pass these variables into each implementation of `operator()`. And yes I'm ok with the scope of the objects being limited to the catch blocks.

Comment: @wmjdgla as I wrote, the actual functions to be executed can be injected at runtime. I only added as much as was needed to reproduce your example. " I'm not sure if there is a clean way to pass ..." yes there is a clean way. State what you need and we can tell you how it can be done (without exceptions)

Comment: Offtopic: I do not like to see `== true` in code. It is boiler plate expression. Also comparing integer value to `true` requires a bit more knowledge about C++ details (implicit conversions) from reader then simple equivalent `x == 1`.

Comment: `Different handlers require different variables. I'm not sure if there is a clean way to pass these variables into each implementation of operator()` what's wrong with just taking references in function object's constructor?

Comment: @alagner Which means I'll need a constructor for each function object, and it'll have to copy all the needed variables. This is an additional layer of abstraction and requires additional maintenance effort, since any changes to the handlers and/or callers of GetObject may require changes to the variables that are passed into the function objects, which in turn requires changes to the constructor. I would like to avoid it if possible.